# python - sending byte arrays via UDP without lists or pickling?

Tags: python, udp, arrays

I am working on a project in which a UDP connection must be used to send an arbitrary file between two unix machines. The main crux of the project is to encode data into byte arrays and send them between the two machines. My original plan was to take byte arrays, form a list out of them, and then serialize them with pickle and send. However, I was just told today by my instructor that using lists and serializing with pickle was not an acceptable solution to the problem. To quote his words:

"You have to encode and decode integer, string, and file objects by yourself, so that you obey the protocol defined in the handout." [this protocol refers to creating segments out of byte arrays, each segment holding 4-byte array for file size, 2-byte array for file name, and 1-byte array for ID flag, as well as a 'payload' byte array which varies in length based on what is being sent.]

I'm not really sure to go with it at this point. I have byte arrays that I need to send to the other machine, but my first two ideas to do so have been disallowed. I can make the byte arrays and the UDP connections (both of which I have tested independently), but sending them is tripping me up. Is there a good solution to my python problem?

Answer (score 0):

A byte array in Python is best represented by a `str` (a simple string).  Your work will probably be to create that byte array according to that protocol specification you got.  Take care that it is a `str` then, and send it via the network functions for accessing sockets.

To convert a list of integers (bytes) into a `str`, use the following:

```
''.join(chr(c) for c in integer_list)
```

Or maybe you can build the `str` right in the first place (without going via a list of numbers).

Comment: Tried this and got the following error (in a test program):

TypeError: an integer is required

I tried changing the line posted to join(int(c) for c in integer_list) and got a different error:

TypeError: sequence item 0: expected string, int found

Not sure what to change about the function to make it work out. I'll keep trying things though.

Comment: If you use `int` then you will end up with a list of `int`s, and `join` wants to join `str`s only; `chr` creates a single-char string of type `str`, so stick to the version I posted; your trial change was in the wrong direction.  I guess from the error message that your `integer_list` does not contain (only) integers.  You can give it out using `print` for debugging.