# Python: packaging multiple byte arrays

Tags: python, struct, arrays

This is a continuation of a previous question. I have gotten more correspondence, but I have a little confusion as to following that advice.

My intent is to take several byte arrays of varying lengths and send them to a process on another machine via UDP. The UDP I can do, but sending the byte arrays is troubling me, as not only must I convert them into something that sendto will accept, but I also must combine the several byte arrays together for sending as one object.

For this problem, I have been advised to use struct.pack and struct.unpack, but I'm not sure of how to  use these functions. The examples I was given did not work as I expected and searching online has not done much to help. This assignment requires that the several byte arrays be sent as one object, which further complicates things as I don't understand how to pack multiple byte arrays into one object and still be able to both send it through UDP and access each part independently once received. Can anyone provide help with understanding how struct.pack and struct.unpack could help with these challenges?

I have also stumbled upon another concept, of encoding and decoding strings and bytes. I'm still testing it and it seems promising as a solution to my problem, but I'm still not sure if it will be capable of doing what I need. If anyone could help shed some light on this as well, then I would really appreciate it.

For the record, I have been told to not use lists or pickle in my solution.

EDIT: Here's the test code I've been trying for encode and decode. I sourced this partially from another SO question, so I'm not 100% on what all is happening. Would this kind of thing work for my needs?

```
import socket
import struct
import sys

newbyte = bytearray(4)
mewbyte = bytearray(2)
oewbyte = bytearray(1)

newbyte = sys.argv[1]

stringbyte = newbyte.decode("utf-8")

print "newbyte", newbyte
print "stringbyte", stringbyte

ideabyte = stringbyte.encode("utf-8")

print "ideabyte", ideabyte
```

EDIT: For more completeness, this is the struct.pack example I was shown which gave me trouble. It seems simple enough, but seems like it needs something different to work with byte arrays.

```
   >> import struct
   >> var = 1000       # an integer variable
   >> byte_int = struct.pack('<I', var)
```

Comment: link to previous question about this topic: 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19637989/python-sending-byte-arrays-via-udp-without-lists-or-pickling

The scenario changed and thus I felt it best to ask a new version of the question rather than attempt to update that one. If this was improper, than I apologize!

Comment: How big are these byte arrays and how many are you planning on sending at once? If the total size of one packet is smaller than ~500 octets, it's guaranteed not to fragment.

Comment: Byte arrays are not allowed to exceed 1200, average payload will be around 1000 bytes. We haven't talked about fragmentation, so I don't believe it was concern for this assignment.